# How to choose iterator direction at runtime

Tags: c++, iterator

I'd like to choose the direction to iterate over a container at runtime, like in the following sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void iterate(bool forward, std::vector<int> v) {
  auto start = v.begin();
  auto end = v.end();
  if (!forward) {
    start = v.rbegin(); // this doesn't
    end = v.rend();     // work
  }

  for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << " -> " << *std::next(it) << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  iterate(true, v);
  iterate(false, v);
}
```

**How can I change the iterator direction at runtime, without duplicating the for loop?**

Imagine the loop being a rather complex algorithm that you don't want to duplicate to avoid future maintenance issues. Note that I need access to the std::next/std::previous element in the loop body.

Comment: Maybe `++it` --> `it += begin < end ? 1 : -1`?  - or use a pre-computed `it += direction`.

Comment: That would work, however there's lots of access to std::previous(it) and std::next(it) in the loop body, which then would need to be flipped around depending on the direction.

Comment: Maybe a variant of forward and reverse iterators which you then visit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a little bit of indirection, ie, using a helper function you can make a call to a template function that accepts the iterator types you want to loop with like

```
template<typename Iterator>
void iterate_helper(Iterator start, Iterator end)
{
    for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it) 
    {
        std::cout << *it << " -> " << *std::next(it) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void iterate(bool forward, std::vector<int> v)
{
        if (!forward)
            iterate_helper(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
        else
            iterate_helper(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

---

Just in case this example code is real code, do note that `*std::next(it)` in the for loop is going to go one past the end of the container.  Your end condition needs to stop one before `end` to use it.

Comment: Couldn't you use a polymorphic lambda (c++17) and keep everything in one function?

Comment: @Botje That's definitely another option.  I used a function here since I normally save lambdas for one liners.

Comment: I doubt `!forward` is intended to mean "backwards then forward", typo fixed.

Comment: Of course the loop body is just an example. I would't make such an effort if that was all there is to it ;) The actual body has a bunch of checks for not running over the beginning/end.

Comment: I went with this suggestion. The code is still nice and readable in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Some boilerplate.  Some of the helper stuff has implementations in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)/[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) std library.  Parts of this implementation requires [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  bool empty() const { return begin() == end(); }

  // in a real implementation, this should check if the iterators are
  // random access, and if so do the simple implementation.  I don't
  // want to use std::distance, because if n is small compared to the
  // distance from begin to end, that could get expensive.
  range_t except_last( std::size_t n = 1 ) const {
    if (n==0 || empty()) return *this;
    if (n==1) return { begin(), std::prev(end()) };
    return except_last((n-1)/2).except_last(1+(n-1)/2);
  }
};

template<class C>
auto range( C&& c ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return range_t{ begin(c), end(c) };
}

template<class C>
auto backwards( C&& c ) {
  using std::rbegin; using std::rend;
  return range_t{ rbegin(c), rend(c) };
}

template<class T>
struct index_iterator {
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using value_type = T;
  using reference = T;
  T t;
  T operator*() const { return t; }
  T const* operator->() const { return std::addressof(t); }
  index_iterator& operator++() { ++t; return *this; }
  index_iterator operator++(int) { auto r = *this; ++t; r; }
  friend bool operator==(index_iterator const& lhs, index_iterator const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t==rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(index_iterator const& lhs, index_iterator const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t!=rhs.t;
  }
};

template<class C>
auto iterators_into( C&& c ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return range_t{ index_iterator{begin(c)}, index_iterator{end(c)} };
}

template<class R, class Op>
void foreach_adjacent( R&& r, Op&& op ) {
  for( auto it : iterators_into( r ).except_last() ) {
    op( *it, *std::next(it) );
  }
}
```

This is the result of having that boilerplate around:

```
void iterate(bool forward, std::vector<int> v) {
  auto op = [](auto&& first, auto&& second) {
    std::cout << first << " -> " << second << std::endl;
  };
  if (forward) 
    foreach_adjacent( v, op ):
  else
    foreach_adjacent( backwards(v), op );
}
```

what is going on:

`range_t` is a wrapper for a non-owning range of elements using iterators.

`backwards` and `range` create forward and backwards `range_t`s based off an input container or range.

`index_iterator` is an input iterator over a range of iterators.  With `iterators_into`, it lets you simply loop over a range of a container with a `for(:)` loop, but get the **iterators** not the elements at each step.  (Note that `index_iterator` can also accept `std::size_t` instead of `iterator`s; that is what I usually use it for.  Both iterators and integers model the concepts it requires for its type argument.)

`.except_last` is a helper method on `range_t` that drops the last `n` (default 1) elements from the range.

`foreach_adjacent` iterates over the iterators of its input, dropping the last element, then calls `op` on each element and the one after it (which is guaranteed to exist, because we dropped the last element).

In our `iterate` function, we first write the body of the loop `op`, then we either visit adjacent elements forwards or backwards, calling `op`.

Comment: A for effort ;) I will try to understand what you did here later and I'm sure I'm gonna learn something! However, I went with @NathanOliver's suggestion just as you posted your answer.

Comment: @Crazor Good; this is more for enrichment than something you should write at your current level of C++ knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show what I came up with after @Botje mentioned 'polymorphic lambdas'. I recently watched [CppCon 2019: Arthur O'Dwyer “Back to Basics: Lambdas from Scratch”](https://youtu.be/3jCOwajNch0?t=1900) and I'm not quite sure if Arthur's 'Generic Lambdas' are what @Botje means, but the following code works just fine and is rather elegant IMHO:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void iterate(bool forward, std::vector<int> v) {
  auto l = [](auto start, auto end){
    for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it) {
      std::cout << *it << " -> " << *std::next(it) << std::endl;
    }
  };

  if (forward) {
    l(v.begin(), v.end());
  } else {
    l(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  iterate(true, v);
  iterate(false, v);
}
```